# Can I use jQuery Ajax for a file upload in IE9?

Tags: jquery, http, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I am revising code that uses XMLHttpRequest for a file upload. I have just learned that this is a v2 feature and unavailable in IE9. If I swap the ajax call out to jQuery, as discussed in the question, [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6974684/8741), do I have any hope of this working from IE9?

Comment: Did you try if it worked? is there a specific Problem? How does the code look like?

Comment: I'm not asking about it working for me - I'm asking about standards compliance - and having confidence that it will always work, on any machine, in anyone's IE9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: check this **[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)** and the Answer with the comment about IE < 10. In short **No**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this library at work for fileupload via ajax: https://github.com/blueimp/jquery-file-upload.
It is working nicely with IE 9, it can even support CORS if you use a redirect frame.

- Google Chrome
- Apple Safari 4.0+
- Mozilla Firefox 3.0+
- Opera 11.0+
- **Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0+**

It also support the formData you are talking about i think:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata

Comment: I'll check the library thanks, but it doesn't help me that is supports FormData, as IE 9 doesn't. I just have to get around needing FormData.

Comment: in my case the plugin does not work for multiple file select in IE9 under Windows7